# Do Lagrange's multipliers fail in this case?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Question: 
Use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum and minimum values of the function subject to the given constraint. (If an answer does not exist, enter DNE.)

f(x,y)= y^2 - x^2 and (1/4)x^2 + y^2 = 9

I've tried solving it like I would all other questions of this type, but I get λ=4 which doesn't seem right. Am I doing something wrong or is it a DNE situation?

Comment: I get, when I solve the Lagrange equations, $x=0$ (and $\lambda=1$) or $y=0$ (and $\lambda=4$). Then there's a max at $x=0, y=\pm 3$ and a  min at $y=0, x=\pm 6$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Isn´t $\lambda_2=\color{red}-4$ If we change $9$ to $9.01$ the minimum changes from $-36$ to $-36+(-4\cdot 0.01)=-36.04$

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, I can comprehend that. But wouldn´t be then $\lambda_1$ negative if $\lambda_2=4$?

Comment: @callculus, you are right of course.Sorry.

Comment: @ancientmathematician There is no excuse needed. I was just wondering. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: see the max/min [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%2F4%2By%5E2%3D9;+y%5E2-x%5E2%3D-36,+y%5E2-x%5E2%3D9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use $$y^2=9-\frac{1}{4}x^2$$ and you will get a Problem in only one variable:$$f(x,\pm\sqrt{9-\frac{1}{4}x^2})=9-\frac{1}{4}x^2-x^2$$